# Как реагировать на нажатие фигур в QGraphics PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qgraphicsscene

Имеется *PyQt5* программа, строящая `QGraphic`-поле и эллипс на этом поле. Данному эллипсу присвоено свойство `Selectable`, при нажатии мышкой он выделяется, но вот как сделать обработку данного выделения, не знаю. То есть, чтобы при клике на данный эллипс возвращался, сигнал что ли, который бы говорил, что такой-то эллипс был нажат. 
Скажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

**Вид программы:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код: (всё действие происходит в классе `FormBuilder`)**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QGroupBox, \
    QRadioButton, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QPen

WINDOW_HEIGHT = 150
WINDOW_WIDTH = 600
WINDOW_NAME = 'QGraphics Test'


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_qgraphics()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_qgraphics(self): # создаем и настраиваем QGraph
        self.background_graph_scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.brush = QBrush(Qt.green)
        self.pen = QPen(Qt.red)
        self.graphic_view = QGraphicsView(self.background_graph_scene)
        self.graphic_view.setGeometry(0, 0, 10, 10)

        # добавляем эллипс для примера и делаем его selectable
        ellipse = self.background_graph_scene.addEllipse(20, 20, 50, 50, self.pen, self.brush)
        ellipse.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

    def create_layers(self): # подключаем QGraph к Grid
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        background_image_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        background_image_layout.addWidget(self.graphic_view)
        main_layout.addLayout(background_image_layout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_NAME)

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.main_grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        form_builder_object = FormBuilder()
        self.main_grid.addWidget(form_builder_object, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно подключиться к сигналу сцены [`selectionChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#selectionChanged)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,  \
    QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QPen

WINDOW_HEIGHT = 150
WINDOW_WIDTH = 600
WINDOW_NAME = 'QGraphics Test'


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_qgraphics()
        self.create_layers()

    def handleSelection(self):
        ss = self.background_graph_scene.selectedItems()
        if (len(ss) == 0):
            print('пусто')
        else:
            for s in ss:
                print(s.boundingRect())

    def create_qgraphics(self):  # создаем и настраиваем QGraph
        self.background_graph_scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.background_graph_scene.selectionChanged.connect(
            self.handleSelection)
        self.brush = QBrush(Qt.green)
        self.pen = QPen(Qt.red)
        self.graphic_view = QGraphicsView(self.background_graph_scene)
        self.graphic_view.setGeometry(0, 0, 10, 10)

        # добавляем эллипс для примера и делаем его selectable
        ellipse = self.background_graph_scene.addEllipse(
            20, 20, 50, 50, self.pen, self.brush)
        ellipse.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

        ellipse2 = self.background_graph_scene.addEllipse(
            120, 20, 50, 50, self.pen, self.brush)
        ellipse2.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

    def create_layers(self):  # подключаем QGraph к Grid
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        background_image_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        background_image_layout.addWidget(self.graphic_view)
        main_layout.addLayout(background_image_layout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_NAME)

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.main_grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        form_builder_object = FormBuilder()
        self.main_grid.addWidget(form_builder_object, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Или если хочется отлавливать сами клики, то создать кастомный `QGraphicsItem` и переопределить метод [mousePressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#mousePressEvent)

Comment: да.. если вы увидите кучу уведомлений с моими комментариями, то не обращайте внимания, что-то я в ступор какой-то вошёл, задавал вам вопрос, после сам решал его и так 6 раз. По итогу всё получилось, что нужно было. Спасибо за ваш ответ! Птица классная у вас на аватарке)